# Facebook auto scroll post like news tickers

Tags: php, jquery, facebook-graph-api

I want to develop a page where post feed from facebook can be searched.I am abel to develop the search function but i want the feeds to come continually with out refreshing the page(like facebook home page feeds).I think i need help of jquery but coundn't find a way out.
[here](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/wrangling-with-the-facebook-graph-api/) is a page which helped me to read the post from facebook using graph api and facebook php sdk ..
Any reply will be very helpful..

Comment: Its called long-polling, push or comet, research thos technologies and then some back with a specific question and show what you have tried.

Comment: thanks for your reply..i tried this piece of code but it didn't worked..`$.ajax({
            
            url: "http://graph.facebook.com/100000414454659",
   type: "GET",
   dataType: 'json',
      

            async: true, 
            cache: false,
   
            timeout:50000, 

            success: function(data){ 
   
                addmsg("new", data); 
                setTimeout(
                    'waitForMsg()', 
                    1000 
                );
            },
           error: function (xhr, status, errorThrown) {
  
}
        });`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally i was able to get news feed like search result from facebook..i used jquery and facebook javascript sdk for this... here are some code..

```
 function waitForMsg(){

    FB.api('/search?q=good&type=post&since='+ts, function(response) {

        if(response.data.length>0)
        {
        for(var i=0;i<response.data.length;i++)
        {
       $("#messages").prepend("<div class='msg '>"+ response.data[i].message +" @"+response.data[i].created_time+"</div>");

        }

        ts = Math.round((new Date()).getTime() / 1000);
        }
    });
    };
```

and i called this function using set interval function like this

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
      setInterval(function(){waitForMsg()},10000);
      });
```

Now please do some google for the FB.api() thing..  :)